# New column with incremental occurance, like countif($A$2:A2,A2) in excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, countif

I would like to get a new column of Occurance like df2. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['1','2','1','3','4','2','1']})
print(df)

#my ideal case
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':['1','2','1','3','4','2','1'],'Occurance':['1','1','2','1','1','2','3']})
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `groupby` function with `cumcount`:

```
df["Occurence"] = df.groupby("A").cumcount() + 1  # +1 since cumcount starts at 0
```

**Output:**

```
    A   Occurence
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   1   2
3   3   1
4   4   1
5   2   2
6   1   3
```

Comment: Yes. You answer my question. Thanks